# Unable to add inline style on click

Tags: javascript, css, for-loop

I'm unable to make this code work property. Focus is on `style`, because everything else is working just fine.

```
for (var i = 0; i < apartments.length; i++) {
 apartments[i].click(function(e){

  var popupWrap = document.getElementById('front-view');
  var popup = popupWrap.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
  var el = document.getElementsByClassName('popup');

  popup.className = 'popup';
  popup.innerHTML = "<h4>" + this.data("id") + "</h4>";
  el.style.color = 'red';
 });
}
```

In console it show me this message

> `el.style` is undefined

Comment: You have apsolute instead of absolute in your css, have you tried logging el to see if you actually had an element ?

Comment: .getElementsByClassName returns a node collection and not a single node. thus style is undefined. As a side note you  have a typo on `apsolute`

Comment: Sorry guys that line of css is not needed, i delete it now

Comment: @fcalderan so it's better to use ID?

Comment: @Stefan if you end up with just one element having a certain class, it's probably a good candidate for it not being a class at all. So yes, you could use an id instead.

Comment: you can use el[0] to select the first element. then you can use `el[0].style.color`. Or just `el[2].style.color`

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca yes, it's just one element that i create on click. Thank you, didn't expect that node collection will make a problem here

Comment: Just to confirm, ID do the "trick"